# Gitalb SSH into ubuntu server

Tags: gitlab

in my local dev windows machine I generated shh key using PuttyGen. I also pasted public key into gitlab ssh keys section so now are linked.

I can correcty use ssh now from my windows manchine but I want to use it also in my production server which uses ubuntu.

For example I wan to ssh clone a repository into my ubuntu machine, where and how should I add the ssh keys to my ubuntu server so I can link it with gitlab.

I used this tutorial to generate ssh keys in windows with Putty.

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1421/how-to-create-a-ssh-key-to-work-with-github-and-gitlab-using-puttygen-in-windows-10

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 0):

> How should I add the ssh keys to my Ubuntu server so I can link it with GitLab?

Ideally, you would create a *dedicated* key pair on your Ubuntu server, in order to be able to clone GitLab repositories.

On that Ubuntu server, go to your $HOME folder of your account '`user`' (replace user by the actual user name you are login with on that server).

```
cd

# assuming you do not have a default key yet:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# copy ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to your GitLab account

# Check the key is working
ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com

# Use your key to clone repositories
git clone git@gitlab.com:me/myRepository
```